# adal.js for different backend

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to implement something like in the link below. Could someone let me know how to access secure third party APIs using this token.

For ex : my web app is at http://localhosthost:8080/ui/
         and Web APIs at http://localhosthost:8080/rest-api/

I still donot see any token attached with the request.

Here is my code

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider,    
adalAuthenticationServiceProvider) {
 $routeProvider
 .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/package.html", requireADLogin: true,})
  .when("/dashboard", {templateUrl: "partials/package.html", controller: "searchCtrl", requireADLogin: true,})
  .when("/create", {templateUrl: "partials/upload.html", controller: "packageCtrl", requireADLogin: true,})
   $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });

var endpoints = {
    // Map the location of a request to an API to a the identifier of the associated resource
    "http://localhost:8081/rest-api/":
        "http://localhost:8081/rest-api/",
};
  adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
        {
        tenant: 'common',
        clientId: '',
           extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
        endpoints: endpoints
        },
        $httpProvider
        );
```

}]);

Comment: Did you understand how to create the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only dealing with a single AAD server for authentication, you need to map the API url to the client id token:

```
var clientId = 'some guid';
var endpoints = {
        "http://localhost:8081/rest-api/": clientId,
    };

 adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
        {
        tenant: 'common',
        clientId: clientId,
        extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
        endpoints: endpoints
        },
        $httpProvider
        );
```

This tells ADAL an HTTP request against a URL that match the property name, use the bearer token stored under the key on the right.

I recommend taking a look at the ADAL function getResourceForEndpoint (as of v1.0.14) - this function output determines if ADAL-angular appends the authentication header to the request, and which bearer token is used.

Answer (score -1):

Endpoints are for CORS api request at different hosts. You can see sample here https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-WebAPI-AngularJS-DotNet

ADAL.js compares the endpoint to attach tokens for CORS api calls.

Your service endpoint url could be different than specified endpoints. You can see the token attachment logic inside ProtectedResourceInterceptor at adal-angular.js